# sqlite3 cannot add multiple tables to db using qmark method

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to create several tables in db useing sequence

my code is:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('d:/db.sqlite')
c = con.cursor()
stations = [("station1"), ("station2"), ("station3"]
c.executemany("CREATE TABLE ? ('id_station' integer NOT NULL, 'name' varchar NOT NULL, 'date' varchar NOT NULL", stations)
```

I have got: IndentationError: unexpected indent

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Missing a bracket? `stations = [("station1"), ("station2"), ("station3")]

Comment: of course missing bracket is a mistake, but corretion changes nothing:( maybe someone knows how to create multiple tables with names from list? maybe there is other way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, lets say that I would like to create a **test** table:

##### Create table:

```py
qry = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    id_station INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    DATE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
)
"""
c.execute(qry)
```

Here I have defined the primary key and also a default value for the date field,

##### Insert values

```py
stations = [("station1",), ("station2",), ("station3",)] # Add comma on each tuple
c.executemany("INSERT INTO test (name) values (?)", stations)
```

Pay attention to the tuple format here, make sure there is a comma at the end: ("station1"**,**)

##### Retreive the datas

```py
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
for e in c.fetchall():
    print(e)
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 'station1', '2021-06-03')
(2, 'station2', '2021-06-03')
(3, 'station3', '2021-06-03')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it works. I prepared sql with variable containig table name and execute it with the loop

Comment: Your welcome, don't hesitate to have a read at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm to learn more about using sqlite with python